# Finding the mean of X given the following CDF

Tags: self-study, mean, cumulative-distribution-function

X has the following CDF
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x < 0\\
     x/2                
&\text{if } 0 < x < 1\\
(x^2 - 1)/6 + (1/2) 
&\text{if } 1 < x < 2\\
1 &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
My attempt:

Find the mean of X. So mean = E(x).

$$ 
E(x) = 0 + \int_{0}^{1}x(x/2)dx + \int_{1}^{2}(x * (x^2-1)/6) + 1/2) dx 
$$

Now here is my confusion should I also do the integral of 1 by doing 
$$ \int_{2}^{x}(x*1)dx $$
And solve for x or do I just evaluate the others and get my answer by adding them all together?

Comment: The expectation of $X$ is $\int x f_{X}(x)\, dx $ not $\int x F_{X}(x)\, dx $. Essentially, you're using the CDF not the PDF.

Comment: @stablemarkets Nonsense! The density is the _derivative_ of the CDF, not the integral.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. I need to take the derivative of all of them separately then take integral and get the sum to get $E|X|$

Comment: Sort of, pdf is derivative of CDF, mean is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xd\text{CDF}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\text{ pdf}dx$

Comment: You need to add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: This might be pedantic but the domains above should he changed such that the function is càdlàg.

Comment: @Stats The pedantry is superfluous because $F$ is already continuous everywhere.

Comment: @DilipSarwate oh god you're right. idk what i was thinking. I think the neurons in my brain misfired. I meant derivative.

Answer (score 4):

There is a general formula that avoids deriving the pdf first, namely that
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^2 \{1-F(x)\}\,\text{d}x$$
as explained in that [Stack Exchange entry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172857/14893):
\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[X]&=\int_0^2 x\,\text{d}F(x)\\
&=-\int_0^2 x\,\text{d}(1-F)(x)\\
&=-x(1-F(x))\vert_{x=0}+x(1-F(x))\vert_{x=2}+\int_0^2 (1-F(x))\,\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^2 \{1-F(x)\}\,\text{d}x\end{align*}
by an integration by parts.

Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^1 \{1-x/2\}\,\text{d}x+\int_1^2 \left\{1-\frac{x^2 - 1}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\right\} \,\text{d}x$$